# how to move file to specific folder(unicode) in python

Tags: python, unicode, file-move

I want to move the files to a specific folder.
However, due to a problem with Unicode, the file is not being moved.

```
import os
import shutil

file=r"c:/test/test.rar"
folder=r"c:/test/発射"

shutil.move(file, folder)
#os.rename(file, os.path.join(folder, os.path.split(file)[1]))
```

"shutil.move" and "os.rename" return "[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename" and "WindowsError: [Error 123] file name". They do not recognize Unicode filename.
I searched for many solutions, but I could not solve them.
Can this be solved?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: One missed thing here is a definition of script encoding, a line looking like "# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-". See [PEP263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since NT 3 version, Windows has natively allowed unicode file names provided characters are in the Basic Multilingual Plane (unicode code less or equal to U+FFFF). Simply, you should add a '/' to the folder name. So this should work in Python 3 if the folder exists:

```
file="c:/test/test.rar"
folder="c:/test/\u767a\u5c04/"

shutil.move(file, folder)
```

I forced the unicode code for the non ascii characters, because an editor could use a wrong encoding

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode folder name with system's encoding:

```
import sys

folder = r"c:/test/発射".encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
```

Also, if you wants to use `os.rename` I recommend you to rewrite your line in such manner:

```
os.rename(file, os.path.join(folder, os.path.basename(file)))
```